# How to use unique filter in controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to filter an array by unique category in controller and then use the filtered array with `ng-repeat` in html page. My array is:

```
$scope.tabs = [
                {OBJECTID:1, TYPES:8, Category:"Pharmacies",Name_EN:"antonis" , text : "Home"},
                {OBJECTID:2, TYPES:8, Category:"Opticians",Name_EN:"antonis" , text : "Games"},
                {OBJECTID:3, TYPES:8, Category:"Doctors", Name_EN:"antonis" , text : "Mail"},
                {OBJECTID:4, TYPES:8, Category:"Clinics", Name_EN:"antonis" , text : "Car"},
                {OBJECTID:5, TYPES:8, Category:"Clinics", Name_EN:"antonis" , text : "Profile"},
                {OBJECTID:6, TYPES:8, Category:"Clinics", Name_EN:"antonis" , text : "Favourites"},
                {OBJECTID:7, TYPES:8, Category:"Pharmacies",Name_EN:"antonis" , text : "Chats"},
                {OBJECTID:8, TYPES:4, Category:"Sights",Name_EN:"antonis" , text : "Settings"},
                {OBJECTID:9, TYPES:4, Category:"Meuseums",Name_EN:"antonis"  ,text : "Home"},
                {OBJECTID:10, TYPES:4, Category:"Meuseums",Name_EN:"antonis1" , text : "Home"}  

            ];
```

the filtered array will be like this:

```
$scope.FilteredArray = [
                {Category:"Pharmacies"},
                {Category:"Opticians"},
                {Category:"Doctors"},
                {Category:"Clinics"},
                {Category:"Sights"},
                {Category:"Meuseums"},

            ];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what would be the results of the filtered array ?

Answer (score 4):

Use `unique` `filter` inside `controller` and apply `ng-repeat` on filtered array

```
//Filtered array
      $scope.filteredArray =  $filter('unique')($scope.tabs,'Category');

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="tab in filteredArray">{{tab.Category}}</li>
</ul>
```

Filter

```
angular.module('myapp').filter('unique', function () {

  return function (items, filterOn) {

    if (filterOn === false) {
      return items;
    }

    if ((filterOn || angular.isUndefined(filterOn)) && angular.isArray(items)) {
      var hashCheck = {}, newItems = [];

      var extractValueToCompare = function (item) {
        if (angular.isObject(item) && angular.isString(filterOn)) {
          return item[filterOn];
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      };

      angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
        var valueToCheck, isDuplicate = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < newItems.length; i++) {
          if (angular.equals(extractValueToCompare(newItems[i]), extractValueToCompare(item))) {
            isDuplicate = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!isDuplicate) {
          newItems.push(item);
        }

      });
      items = newItems;
    }
    return items;
  };
});
```

**[FULL EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/04885499/13/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it without angular filter. If you have used `lodash` module in your angular application then you can simply do it with below `lodash` function. It will return uniq records by whatever key you want.

```
_.uniqBy([{ 'x': 1 }, { 'x': 2 }, { 'x': 1 }], 'x');
// => [{ 'x': 1 }, { 'x': 2 }]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this too,

```
  $scope.unique = {};
  $scope.distinct = [];
  for (var i in $scope.tabs) {
    if (typeof($scope.unique[$scope.tabs[i].Category]) == "undefined") {
      $scope.distinct.push($scope.tabs[i].Category);
    }
    $scope.unique[$scope.tabs[i].Category] = 0;
  }
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/48SICVZFjg3e64tQTkV1?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Use the default unique filter:

```
<select ng-model="tab" ng-repeat="uni in tabs | unique:'Category'">
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I would like to filter the array in controller not in html page.so this not the solution.

Comment: using lodash.js or underscore.js   var t = _.uniq($scope.tab, 'Category'),

Answer (score 0):

That code could be used to create a method this will give you an array of strings also you can modify to create object array -

```
var flags = [], $scope.FilteredArray= [], l = $scope.tabs.length, i;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    if( flags[$scope.tabs[i].Category]) continue;
    flags[$scope.tabs[i].Category] = true;
    $scope.FilteredArray.push($scope.tabs[i].Category);
}
```